# Find numbers $a$ and $b$

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, decimal-expansion

Find two numbers $ a$ and $b $ such that the digits of $b$ are the same digits as $a$ in
another order and the number $a - b$ has all the digits equal to $1$?

All I did was essentially just trial and error.

My solution:

$a=234567901$
$b=123456790$

Essentially, the main idea is that we know that most of the digits of $a$ would be $1$ more than the corresponding digits of $b$. Since $a$ and $b$ must use the same digits, we want to make $b$ something like $1234\ldots$, and $a$ would look like $2345\ldots$. From here, we adjust the last digits of $a$ and $b$ so that $a$ and $b$ have the same digits.

What would be a more elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: I would like to search for solutions with pari/gp, but since a week I cannot start windows and hence not use pari/gp. I do not think that there is an "elegant" way to find a solution. If you found the solution by hand, then congratulations !

Comment: Is this a running contest ?

Comment: @Certainlynotadog Actually, $a-b$ clearly ends in $1$. 

$a-b=111111111$.

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ have the same digits then they have the same "digital root" (look it up!), so the same remainder when you divide by $9$, so $a-b$ is a multiple of $9$, so the digits of $a-b$ add up to a multiple of $9$, so $a-b$ is at least $111,111,111$. That takes away some of the guess work. I note that there are infinitely many correct answers, as you can put any string of digits in front of the $a$ in your solution, if you put the same string of digits in front of $b$.